# Create subobject programmatically, not in SLG0

Tags: abap

When creating a new log object I want the subobject to be created on the fly if it doesn't exist yet.
This is what I have right now:

```
ls_log-object     = mc_log_object.
ls_log-subobject  = mv_log_subobject.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_LOG_CREATE'
  EXPORTING
    i_s_log      = ls_log
  IMPORTING
    e_log_handle = mv_log_handle.
```

In order to avoid an error I check the object and subobject like this before:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_OBJECT_SUBOBJECT_CHECK'
  EXPORTING
    i_object            = mc_log_object
    i_subobject         = mv_log_subobject
  EXCEPTIONS
    object_not_found    = 1
    subobject_not_found = 2
    subobject_necessary = 3
    OTHERS              = 4.

CASE sy-subrc.
  WHEN 2.
    mv_log_subobject = ''.
ENDCASE.
```

But I don't want to do it like this, I want to create a new subobject if it doesn't exist yet!
Is there some secret function call that can do this? :D

Comment: @vwegert simply because I'm too lazy to create a new subobject everytime something new is added :D

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the question and what product you're talking about...

Comment: @Cold_Class, don't be surprised, it's his style of talking. Just useless babble without any helpful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no secret function call or something similar. In fact SLG0 is nothing else than view cluster maintenance call (SM34). But I'm also wondering why you need this? If you need some more or dynamic differentiation of your logs you can you use field "extnumber" which you can set in your structure ls_log.

You can select in SLG1 with this field and also via log api.

Comment: okay, thx - too bad it's not possible, but at least I don't have to try to find it since I know it's not possible :)
I will go with the extnumber I guess